# Wood Elf starting stats

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, ability-scores

I'm starting a new campaign and have decided on a Monk.  I know that chossing to be an Elf gives me a +2 Dex.  For the Wood Elf subclass does that give you an additional +1 Wisdom or does that take the place of the +2 Dex? What I'm understanding so far is that creating a Wood Elf Monk would give me a +2 to Dex and a +1 to Wisdom.

Comment: Just needed the information. You can delete as needed thanks.

Comment: No worries! Duplicates are actually desired, rather than deleted. They help other readers with the same problem find the answer quicker. Thanks for improving our web of questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You are correct

The subclass states that the bonus and other traits are in addition to the baseclass.

A Wood Elf gives you +2 Dex from the Elf base class and +1 Wis from the Wood Elf subclass and your Wood Elf Monk therefore starts with +2 Dex and +1 Wis.

Comment: I guess the exception would be speed. A wood elf doesn't have a speed of 30+35 :-)

Comment: I've read this for the Wood Elf -  Fleet of Foot: Your base walking speed increases to 35 feet.  Is that not right?

Comment: @Fogcutter The subclasses trait overwrites what is written in the base class. Your Wood Elf has a base walking speed of 35 feet. Other Elf subclasses do not change the speed and retain the 30 feet base walking speed from the Elf base class.